# WIFI keeps disconnecting in 14.04

Tags: wireless, disconnect

I am brand spanking new to Ubuntu and finally got it up and running.  Now, it just keeps randomly disconnecting and will reconnect after some number of tries.  It seems to stay connected if I keep on the internet but soon after I leave, it disconnects.

I keep having to go to Windows, like now.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

The installed wireless driver might not be correct for your computer, Try installing the native b43 driver:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And then reboot your computer